# Unable to perform an operation on ArrayList

Tags: java, oop

My intention is to make a shallow clone of the `ArrayList` but before that i am facing an issue while modifying the list.
**Adding the another element in the list giving**

```
UnsupportedOrderException
```

WHY?

```java
class Mine implements Cloneable {
    public List<Integer> list;
    Mine(List<Integer> mylist) {
        this.list = mylist;
    }
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}

class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        List<Integer> klist= Arrays.asList(10,20,30,40,50);
        Mine m1=new Mine(klist);
        m1.list.add(11); // <- why i am unable to add to the list
        Mine m2= (Mine) m1.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AritroShome, `List` is an *interface* that has many implementations, not only `ArrayList`.

Comment: ```List``` is an interface, which itself doesn't have an implementation. Use ```ArrayList<T>``` instead, that implements ```List```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot change the number of elements of the `List` (using `add()` or `remove()` or similar) returned by `Arrays.asList` (but it allows to change elements using `.set()`).

From [the docs of `Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

> The returned list implements the optional Collection methods, **except those that would change the size of the returned list**. Those methods leave the list unchanged and throw UnsupportedOperationException.

Instead, you can create an `ArrayList` with the same elements:

```
List<Integer> klist= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10,20,30,40,50));
```

Comment: In general, In would use `Arrays.asList` only if you plan to never modify that `List`.

Comment: @dan1st  Is it wrong to do something like ```ArrayList<MyObject> = Arrays.asList(myObjectArray);``` ?

Comment: Yes, this would not work because it does not create an `ArrayList` but only tries to assign to an `ArrayList` resulting in a compile-time error because `Arrays.asList` does not return a `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: I have added a link to the docs.

Answer (score 4):

[`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) returns a `List<T>` implementation that is backed by the original array. (Changed to the array can be seen via the list and vice versa.)

Arrays have a fixed size in Java, therefore the list returned by `Arrays.asList` has to have a fixed size as well - you can't add to it, and you can't remove from it.

You can create a new `ArrayList<T>` instead, which creates a *copy* of the array:

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...));
```

Although `ArrayList` is still backed by an array, it will create a new array where necessary. The array is an implementation detail, rather than the list being a "view" over an existing array as is returned by `Arrays.asList`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @dan1st's answer (and now @JonSkeet as well), you can create your own `asList()` method to return a *mutable* `List<T>`:

```
static public List<T> asMutableList(T ... elts) {
    List<T> lst = new ArrayList<>(elts.length);
    for (T el : elts) {
        lst.add(el);
    }
    return lst;
}
```